# Ubuntu 13.04 Screen Brightness Only Changes Via Hotkeys

Tags: brightness, 13.04

This is a new problem I'm facing in 13.04, and is not related to what worked for 12.10 or earlier.

In 12.10, I had the `acpi_backlight=vendor` in my grub in order to make the brightness setting work. However, this does not work on 13.04. I don't even see a brightness bar.

To change that, I tried `acpi_osi=` and the brightness bar appeared in the system settings. Moving it doesn't change the brightness, but using my hotkeys does.

Since Ubuntu doesn't remember the brightness settings between boots, I had a script that would adjust it during startup. Now, even that doesn't seem to work. Only my hotkeys work at the moment.

#### Laptop information:

- Model: Acer Aspire E1-571
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4
- Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
- OS type: 64bits

#### Things I've tried

- `acpi_osi=`  *using this makes my hotkeys work, but the brightness slider doesn't work*
- `acpi_osi=Linux`
- `acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'`
- `acpi_osi='!Windows 2012' acpi_backlight=vendor`
- `acpi_backlight=vendor`

Comment: Can you add what kind of laptop it is to your question?

Comment: @JorgeCastro: I've added my Laptop's specifications

Answer (score 2):

Try using `acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'` the same way you would use `acpi_backlight=vendor`
that fixed it for me, another one to try is `acpi_osi=Linux`

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Toshiba Satellite R830. Actually using !Widnows 2012 makes matters worse.

Comment: This didn't work. Adding '!Windows 2012' makes my hotkeys stop working.

Comment: have you tried this one ``acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=``

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary(?) solution I boot Ubuntu 13.04 64bit with my latest Ubunt 12.10 64bit kernel ( so I boot with 3.5.0-27-generic, not with the newest 3.8.0-19-generic)

I've also kept the old /etc/default/grub file that I used in 12.10 (where I had to add acpi_backlight=vendor to make my brightness keys Fn-leftt and Fn-right function)

Comment: If it works on the 3.5 and not the 3.8 and you needed `acpi_backlight=vendor` try `acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'` with the 3.8 kernel

Comment: acpi_osi ='!Windows 2012' (that is Windows 8) works only if you have a BIOS that knows what do with that information. My BIOS goes until 'Windows 2009', so it will not be able to handle that information.